# Need suggestions on interactive Javascript based map

Tags: javascript, dictionary

can anyone help identify the Javascript library used for interactive maps on http://www.africatravelresource.com/

Or is it a custom solution? Any suggestions for something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google GeoCharts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html) which provide an interactive interface. I, personally, find these very helpful and easy to use. Also, the maps cover just about any area of the world.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion brad. Looks interesting. Any idea on what africatravelresource.com is using?

Comment: @JatinderThind: A _very_ simple [Image Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/map) (and probably something like [maphighlight](http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/maphilight-image-map-mouseover-highlighting/) for visual effect).

Answer (score 0):

Similar functionality is provided by the [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com) library. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do "slippy maps" in Javascript (like google maps) then look at OpenLayers - it would be a bit heavyweight for that africa travel site though.

There's a few other lighter javascript mapping systems - Leaflet is one... They're open source, and integrate with OpenStreetMap background maps so you aren't relying on google's licensing...